# Jquery Autocomplete: static list or php query: limit

Tags: jquery

I have an autocomplete dropdown with a PHP source that queries a database. I am wondering if I should optimize it and either:

- send the whole list of fields
- write the list on php and use it to limit the results
- use php and query the db ( `select * from blabla where name like`...)

The list of items is made of 11000 items and it's not updated frequently. I decide when I want to change it.

I'd like to optimize it because my Db is already under pressure with other queries and maybe I should avoid using it for trivial stuff like this.

Comment: Which jQuery Plugin do you use (if any)? Did you check [this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) out?

Answer (score 0):

The third one, I think. Since it will save more time on querying and there's no necessary filtering needed

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, a static list would be very fast in execution and would not account for overhead of fetching the data every time a user types in some text. So according to me it would be good to create a static array in javascript (with all 11000 values) from the data values and use that array as the source list of your autocomplete ! Let me know if more explanation is needed !